# Hide scroll bar when page preloader loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide scroll bar while preloader is loading the scroll bar will not show until unless preloader disappears which means the user can't able to scroll the page while preloader is loading here I'm using canvas as a preloader. I tried by using body overflow: hidden and some CSS also but unable to achieve the result here I used canvas effect as a preloader. Can anyone point me in the right direction what I'm doing wrong?

```js
/* Preloader Effect */
var noise = function(){
//const noise = () => {
    var canvas, ctx;

    var wWidth, wHeight;

    var noiseData = [];
    var frame = 0;

    var loopTimeout;


    // Create Noise
    const createNoise = function() {
        const idata = ctx.createImageData(wWidth, wHeight);
        const buffer32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer);
        const len = buffer32.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                buffer32[i] = 0xff000000;
            }
        }

        noiseData.push(idata);
    };


    // Play Noise
    const paintNoise = function() {
        if (frame === 9) {
            frame = 0;
        } else {
            frame++;
        }

        ctx.putImageData(noiseData[frame], 0, 0);
    };


    // Loop
    const loop = function() {
        paintNoise(frame);

        loopTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        }, (1000 / 25));
    };


    // Setup
    const setup = function() {
        wWidth = window.innerWidth;
        wHeight = window.innerHeight;

        canvas.width = wWidth;
        canvas.height = wHeight;

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            createNoise();
        }

        loop();
    };


    // Reset
    var resizeThrottle;
    const reset = function() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
            window.clearTimeout(resizeThrottle);

            resizeThrottle = window.setTimeout(function() {
                window.clearTimeout(loopTimeout);
                setup();
            }, 200);
        }, false);
    };


    // Init
    const init = (function() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('noise');
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        setup();
    })();
};

noise();

$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').css({
  overflow: 'hidden'
});
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('body').css({
      overflow: 'auto'
    });
  });
}, 5000);
});
```

```css
#preloader {
 position: fixed;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 5000;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: #fff;
 /* change if the mask should have another color then white */
 z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader">
 <canvas id="noise" class="noise"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: add `overflow: hidden` on your container or even `document.body` elements and then remove this styling when done

Comment: It seems that the piece of code you've shared is working great (no scrolling bar until the preloader is done, tested on Firefox).

Comment: @thibpat because i didn't added dummy text to get scroll. can you please add and check.

Comment: @NikosM. i tried like this document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; but not getting

Comment: add `style.overflow='hidden'` also on your wrapper element which may have scrolling enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `overflow: hidden` and `height: 100vh` both on the `body` and the `html` tags.

```js
/* Preloader Effect */
var noise = function(){
//const noise = () => {
    var canvas, ctx;

    var wWidth, wHeight;

    var noiseData = [];
    var frame = 0;

    var loopTimeout;


    // Create Noise
    const createNoise = function() {
        const idata = ctx.createImageData(wWidth, wHeight);
        const buffer32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer);
        const len = buffer32.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                buffer32[i] = 0xff000000;
            }
        }

        noiseData.push(idata);
    };


    // Play Noise
    const paintNoise = function() {
        if (frame === 9) {
            frame = 0;
        } else {
            frame++;
        }

        ctx.putImageData(noiseData[frame], 0, 0);
    };


    // Loop
    const loop = function() {
        paintNoise(frame);

        loopTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        }, (1000 / 25));
    };


    // Setup
    const setup = function() {
        wWidth = window.innerWidth;
        wHeight = window.innerHeight;

        canvas.width = wWidth;
        canvas.height = wHeight;

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            createNoise();
        }

        loop();
    };


    // Reset
    var resizeThrottle;
    const reset = function() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
            window.clearTimeout(resizeThrottle);

            resizeThrottle = window.setTimeout(function() {
                window.clearTimeout(loopTimeout);
                setup();
            }, 200);
        }, false);
    };


    // Init
    const init = (function() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('noise');
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        setup();
    })();
};

noise();

$(document).ready(function(){
$('body, html').css({
  overflow: 'hidden',
  height: '100vh'
});
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('body, html').css({
      overflow: 'auto',
      height: 'auto'
    });
  });
}, 5000);
});
```

```css
#preloader {
 position: fixed;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 5000;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: #fff;
 /* change if the mask should have another color then white */
 z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader">
 <canvas id="noise" class="noise"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: you are adding overflow hidden to the html, body after preloader loads the hidden class is not removing and stopping to scroll the page.

Comment: i got it. setTimeout you're called only body, not HTML. and body both.

Answer (score 1):

Try these Codes, If it works for you. I found this on StackOverflow. Source: [Disable scrolling when preload a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384844/disable-scrolling-when-preload-a-web-page)

Js Code

```
$(window).load(function() {
      $(".preloader").fadeOut(1000, function() {
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
      });
    });
```

Css Code

```
  .loading {
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .preloader {
      background: #fff;
      position: fixed;
      text-align: center;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }

    .preloader4 {
       position: absolute;
       margin: -17px 0 0 -17px;
       left: 50%;
       top: 50%;
       width:35px;
       height:35px;
       padding: 0px;
       border-radius:100%;
       border:2px solid;
       border-top-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.65);
       border-bottom-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.15);
       border-left-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.65);
       border-right-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.15);
       -webkit-animation: preloader4 0.8s linear infinite;
       animation: preloader4 0.8s linear infinite;
    }
    @keyframes preloader4 {
       from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
       to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes preloader4 {
       from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
       to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
    }
```

Code

```
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body class="loading">
      <div class="preloader">
        <div class="preloader4"></div>
      </div>
//Code

    </body>
```

Comment: overflow-y: hidden !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;

Answer (score 0):

Set the position of `body` as `fixed` and when the page is loaded, remove that.

```js
document.body.style.position = "fixed";
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    document.body.style.position = "";
    document.querySelector(".preloader").style.display = "none";
});
```