# How to hide the scrollbar on pre-loader screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I want to hide the `y-axis` scrollbar on the preloader screen.

[image]

As you can see on the far right, I want to hide that scrollbar on my preloader screen. To do this, would I need to add a `overflow-y: hidden;` on the `preloader css`? I tried doing that but it still did not work.

Here is the code of the preloader:

```js
 $(window).on('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if ($('#preloader').length) {
      $('#preloader').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@500;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;600&family=Oswald:wght@500&family=Pacifico&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,900;1,500&display=swap');



.svg-file path {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke: rgb(1, 36, 133);
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
    stroke-dasharray: 550;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
    animation: animate-zlogo 2s linear infinite;
}

.svg-file.z-logo svg {
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
    transform: scale(2);
}

.svg-file h2 {
    font-family: "Roboto", cursive;
    transform: translate(0, 50px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #044d77;
}

.svg-file span {
    animation: dots 2.5s steps(6, end) infinite;
    font-size: 5em;
    display: block;
    transform: translate(0, 65px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
    background-color: rgb(5, 46, 80);
    width: 8px;
    height: 5px;
}

@keyframes fadein-fadeout {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes animate-zlogo {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: -50;
    }

    20% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 550;
        fill: transparent;
    }

    40% {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
    }

    60% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
        fill: #05f7f9;    
        }

    80% {
        stroke-width: 0;
       fill: #05f7f9;
    }

    100% {
        /* stroke-dashoffset: 0; */
        stroke-width: 3;
        fill: transparent;
    }
}
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.z-logo svg {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.z-logo::before {
  content: "";
    top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <div id="preloader">
        <div class="svg-file z-logo">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 133 133" width="133" height="133">
                <g id="H">
                    <path d="M45.33 78.22L87.67 78.22L87.67 133L121.05 133L121.05 0L87.67 0L87.67 49.33L45.33 49.33L45.33 0L11.95 0L11.95 133L45.33 133L45.33 78.22Z"
                     fill="#47AF9A" />
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Where should I add the `overflow-y: hidden;` in the above code, I tired adding it to the main `*{` but it hid the y-axis scroll bar for my whole website, but I only want it to hide for the preloader screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide scroll bar when page preloader loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571913/hide-scroll-bar-when-page-preloader-loads)

Comment: It worked fine as-is for me in Safari.

Comment: That is because there is no content I showed you, as I only gave the code of the preloader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the overflow from the body of the page so nothing can be scrolled.

```
$(window).on('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if ($('#preloader').length) {
      $('#preloader').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
      document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden"; // remove overflow from body
      $('body').addClass('preload_active'); // add preload_active class
    }
});
```

If using the `addClass` option then you'll need

```
.preload_active {
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

in your CSS.

You will need something to remove the hidden value though. You can also add a class to the body and in the CSS declare `overflow-y: hidden` on this class. Again, you will need some logic that removes the class when the `preloader.length === 0`.